# Visualize a Mesh with Transparency

Tags: 3d, transparency, meshlab

I have been working with Meshlab, using some meshes (Such as the sample "texturedknot.ply"), currently I have two of this meshes active, one inside the other. In order to view the one inside I have been trying to make the first one transparent.

Changing the alpha level in the .ply file did not work or changing the alpha level in Tool>Options. The closest I got was applying a Shader "xray.gdp" but it applies it to both meshes instead of only one.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or do you know of an **alternative** software/way to do this?

Comment: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/Opacity

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Open 3D Model Viewer](http://www.open3mod.com/).

You can put different mesh as 'groups' in a combined mesh, you will be able to select only one group and 'see through' it the other groups in the mesh.

Github repo : https://github.com/acgessler/open3mod/

Comment: link isn't working!

Comment: @I.Omar You can download from here : https://github.com/acgessler/open3mod/releases/tag/1.0